# Is there a better way to look up attributes in an array of arrays?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, gis, openstreetmap

I have a function with a switch statement that looks for a single case and if it doesn't find it, runs default which is another switch statement.  It is basically doing a lookup through my entire array. Im sure there is a better way to do this I am just new to javascript and don't know. Here is a snippet:

```
for(var i=0; i < parks.length; i++) {
    switch (parks[i][6]) {            
        case 'wc' : 
            wc.push(L.marker([parks[i][1], parks[i][2]], {icon: parks[i][4]}).bindpopup("<a href='" + parks[i][3] + "'>" + parks[i][0] + "</a>"));
            break;        
        default :
            switch (parks[i][7]) {            
         case 'grill' : 
            grill.push(L.marker([parks[i][1], parks[i][2]], {icon: parks[i][4]}).bindpopup("<a href='" + parks[i][3] + "'>" + parks[i][0] + "</a>"));
            break;        
         default :
            break;
            break;
    }
}
```

An example of my parks array because everyone is asking:

```
var parks = [
['Spårvagnsparken',59.3298868,18.0031605,'http://leksplay.com/sparvagnsparken', greenIcon, wc, grill, null, null, fence, null, null, null, null],
['Fredhällsparkens plaskdamm',  59.3320485,18.0029481, 'http://leksplay.com/fredhallsparkensplaskdamm', greenIcon, wc, null, null, null, null, null, null, water, null],
['Uggleparken',     59.3343715,18.0040208,'http://leksply.com/uggleparken', greenIcon, wc, null, null, null, null, pfence, null, null, null],
['Observatorielundens Parklek', 59.3413877,18.056007, 'http://leksplay.com/observatorielundensparklek', greenIcon, wc, null, null, null, null, pfence, null, null, toddler],
```

Comment: Please show how the value of `parks` looks like.

Comment: please add an example of `parks`.

Comment: Would be so cool to see an example of that `parks` array - I find it so strange that  more keys are used to store different tags...

Comment: I edited with an example of parks @Roko

Comment: Just to understand something, say one location has two (or more) *props* (i.e: both "wc" and "grill") - you want to place two icons in the same POI location?

Comment: Also, are you sure those are variables and not strings ? `wc` is a variable, while `"wc"` is a String

Comment: @roko i'm building a filterable map using the built-in leaflet layer control. I need the control, which corresponds to each attribute (i.e. wc, grill) to use and logic. So that when wc and grill are selected it shows parks that have both attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your provided array, I would

- It's [`bindPopup`](https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/), not `bindpopup`
- construct a`markers` as Object `{}`
- Retrieve all *(not NULL)* POI's *"props"* (like `"toddler"`, `"wc"` etc)
- Iterate the retrieved props pushing a `newMarker()` into the `markers` Object.

```js
const markers = {};
const newMarker = poi => L.marker([poi.lat, poi.lng], {icon: poi.icon})
                       .bindPopup(`<a href="${poi.url}">${poi.name}</a>`);

const parks = [
  ['Spårvagnsparken', 59.3298868, 18.0031605, 'http://leksplay.com/sparvagnsparken', "greenIcon", "wc", "grill", null, null, "pfence", null, null, null, null],
  ['Fredhällsparkens plaskdamm', 59.3320485, 18.0029481, 'http://leksplay.com/fredhallsparkensplaskdamm', "greenIcon", "wc", null, null, null, null, null, null, "water", null],
  ['Uggleparken', 59.3343715, 18.0040208, 'http://leksply.com/uggleparken', "greenIcon", "wc", null, null, null, null, "pfence", null, null, null],
  ['Observatorielundens Parklek', 59.3413877, 18.056007, 'http://leksplay.com/observatorielundensparklek', "greenIcon", "wc", null, null, null, null, "pfence", null, null, "toddler"],
];

parks.forEach(([name, lat, lng, url, icon, ...props]) => {
  props.filter(Boolean).forEach(prop => {
     if (!(prop in markers)) markers[prop] = []; // Prepare if not exists
     markers[prop].push(newMarker({name, lat, lng, url, icon}));
  });
})

console.log(markers);
```

Example (with objects only, for demo):

```js
const markers = {};
const newMarker = poi => poi;

const parks = [
  ['Spårvagnsparken', 59.3298868, 18.0031605, 'http://leksplay.com/sparvagnsparken', "greenIcon", "wc", "grill", null, null, "pfence", null, null, null, null],
  ['Fredhällsparkens plaskdamm', 59.3320485, 18.0029481, 'http://leksplay.com/fredhallsparkensplaskdamm', "greenIcon", "wc", null, null, null, null, null, null, "water", null],
  ['Uggleparken', 59.3343715, 18.0040208, 'http://leksply.com/uggleparken', "greenIcon", "wc", null, null, null, null, "pfence", null, null, null],
  ['Observatorielundens Parklek', 59.3413877, 18.056007, 'http://leksplay.com/observatorielundensparklek', "greenIcon", "wc", null, null, null, null, "pfence", null, null, "toddler"],
];

parks.forEach(([name, lat, lng, url, icon, ...props]) => {
  props.filter(Boolean).forEach(prop => {
     if (!(prop in markers)) markers[prop] = []; // Prepare if not exists
     markers[prop].push(newMarker({name, lat, lng, url, icon}));
  });
})

console.log(markers);
```

Comment: I have been trying this all day and keep getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: L.marker(...).bindpopup is not a function

Comment: @MichaelPerna I copyed that one from you. You can see in the second snipped how the logic works. The error you're getting is exactly what it says: *`bindpopup` is not a function*. So perhaps you should check the DOCS. Probably a typo?

Comment: https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/ it's `bindPopup`, not `bindpopup` like you posted. Fixed that one too.

Answer (score 0):

Make a function that calls and returns `L.marker`, passing it the array on each iteration when the condition passes. Just use `===` to check if the item at the index is `wc` or `grill`:

```
const makeMarker = park => L.marker([park[1], park[2]], { icon: park[4] })
  .bindpopup("<a href='" + park[3] + "'>" + park[0] + "</a>");
for (const park of parks) {
  if (park[6] === 'wc') {
    wc.push(makeMarker(park));
  } else if (park[7] === 'grill') {
    grill.push(makeMarker(park));
  }
}
```

Ideally, fix your input structure so that instead of different values in positions `[6]`, `[7]`, etc, you have a single array of values there instead, then check the array for different values and add the marker to an object of arrays:

```
const categories = ['wc', 'grill', /* ... */];
const markers = Object.fromEntries(
  categories.map(cat => [cat, []])
);
for (const park of parks) {
  const marker = makeMarker(park);
  const cat = categories.find(cat => park[6].includes(cat));
  markers[cat].push(marker);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, can I build a bunch of else if? I have 9 attributes in my array to  check for.

Comment: Do you also have 9 different arrays to push to? If that's the case, you should use an object of arrays instead of 9 separate variables to make the code DRY

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: @MichaelPerna are you 200% sure you have `park[6]` `park[7]` etc? Why are not both tags `"wc"` or `"grill"` or *whatever* stored under the same array key?

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan yes, it is for another function later.

Comment: @MichaelPerna And how many of those you have? I mean, clearly you have *name, lat, lng, url, icon, etc etc...* I'm asking to better understand your *input* (the `parks` Array), so we can provide a better and simpler code or suggestion...

Comment: @MichaelPerna You should really consider restructuring the array, its current format is extremely convoluted. I'd use an array of values instead: `['wc', 'grill', 'water']` etc

Comment: hi @CertainPerformance could you help me understand what I am missing here? [link to gist](https://gist.github.com/michaelperna/8434cba2c3b1c0f625aa2148f8aa7750).

Comment: @MichaelPerna If you're trying to refactor to my suggestion, the final value in the array should be an *array* (if it contains any indicators), not a string. Eg `['Spårvagnsparken', 59.3298868, 18.0031605, 'http://leksplay.com/sparvagnsparken', greenIcon, ['wc', 'grill', 'fence']]`